# I did a search for my Laravel 5.8 site and it throws me this error: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Tags: laravel

I am writing a simple crud app where you add a search engine and it returns the data that I request. The error it throws at me is the following: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

I have tried several things already. What can I try next? I attach the error and the code of my project so you understand the problem well

My controller:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $registries = DB::table('registries')->where('apellido', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')->paginate(5);
    return view('registries.index', ['registries' => $registries]);
}
```

The route:

```php
Route::get('search', 'RegistryController@search')-> name('search');
```

My index.blade.php:

```html
<thead class="bg-200 text-900">
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sort pr-1 align-middle sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 129.203px;">Apellido</th>
        <th class="sort pr-1 align-middle sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 140.203px;">Nombres</th>
        <th class="sort pr-1 align-middle sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 279.203px;">Dirección</th>
        <th class="sort pr-1 align-middle text-center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 81.2031px;">Teléfono</th>
        <th class="sort pr-1 align-middle text-right sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71.2031px;">Dni</th>
        <th class="no-sort pr-1 align-middle data-table-row-action sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 56.2031px;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($registries as $registry)
    <tr class="btn-reveal-trigger odd" role="row">
        <td class="align-middle">{{$registry['apellido']}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{$registry['nombre']}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{$registry['direccion']}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center fs-0">
            <span class="badge badge rounded-capsule badge-soft-success">
                {{$registry['telefono']}}
                <!-- <span class="ml-1 fas fa-check" data-fa-transform="shrink-2"></span> -->
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-right">{{$registry['dni']}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle white-space-nowrap">
            <div class="dropdown text-sans-serif position-static">
                <button class="btn btn-link text-600 btn-sm dropdown-toggle btn-reveal mr-3" type="button" id="dropdown0" data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="html" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-w-16 fs--1" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="ellipsis-h" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
                        <path
                            fill="currentColor"
                            d="M328 256c0 39.8-32.2 72-72 72s-72-32.2-72-72 32.2-72 72-72 72 32.2 72 72zm104-72c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72zm-352 0c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72z"
                        ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <!-- <span class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fs--1"></span> -->
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right border py-0" aria-labelledby="dropdown0" style="">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('RegistryController@show', $registry['id'])}}">Ver</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('RegistryController@edit', $registry['id'])}}">Editar</a>
                        <form onsubmit="return confirm('Esta seguro que desea borrar los datos?');" action="{{action('RegistryController@destroy', $registry['id'])}}" method="delete">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />
                            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item text-danger">Borrar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

And the screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot or error]

Comment: query builder returns `stdClass` objects, not models, you can not use `stdClass` objects as arrays

Comment: ah ok, but how can I solve the error so that it shows me the variable in the index.blade.php?

Comment: Change all like this `{{ $registry->apellido }}`, good luck.

Comment: stop using the `stdClass` object as an array, because you can't, thats how you solve the error

Comment: {{ $registry->apellido }} instead of ['registries' => $registries] ?

Comment: Change `{{$registry['apellido']}}` to `{{$registry->apellido }}` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a quick fix you can use eloquent instead of database builder,

The controller:

`$registries = App\Registry::where('apellido', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')->paginate(5);`

**Registry** supposed to be the model name or just replace it with model name.

The view:
Replace {{$registry['apellido']}} with {{$registry->apellido}} and the others as well.

Comment: if they change to querying with the model they can use the array syntax

Comment: Am just recommending to use the object syntax.. It feels cleaner